# Azure AdlCopy Error: Invalid JSON Primitive:

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am trying to copy several csv files from an Azure Storage Blob to an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 using AdlCopy in Standalone Mode. The Data Lake Storage folder I am trying to move the data to is currently empty. Here is my CMD script that I am using:

```
C:\Users\username\Applications>AdlCopy /source https://myblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/Folder/SubFolder/SubFolder/ /dest swebhdfs://mydatalakestorage.azuredatalakestore.net/Folder/ /sourcekey mysourcekey
```

When I run the script I am prompted for my credentials. After I enter them this is the error that I get:

```
Initializing Copy.
Invalid JSON primitive: .
Copy Failed.
```

Has anyone else had any experience with this error? I have yet to see any documentation on how to handle this error or what might be causing it. I appreciate any help or guidance!

Comment: Did you also search on "Invalid json primitive"? Looking at your code i don't see any JSON information.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I have done some research on that. From what I understand JSON Primitive types are the allowed data types and formatting standards of JSON objects. I agree with you. I see no evidence of JSON anywhere in the code, nor have I found any documentation from Azure, or elsewhere, explaining if it uses it in some way.

Comment: I could not find any sourcecode in GitHub of this tool. Maybe you can try to use a decompiler like ILSpy to see if this gives you any information about the implementation of this tool.

Comment: As you suggested, I went through the source code using ILSpy. There is definitely some converting going on from various data types to JSON. Unfortunately, I was unable to locate exactly where the error could be coming from. I may contact Microsoft about the issue. If so, I will update their response here.